# Add new Button to LinearLayout at Runtime in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to add new Button at runtime with all properties as in following.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMM"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/android_btn_md"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:onClick="btnMMClick"
                    android:text="M-"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" /> 

 ...... more buttons at design time are here .....
```

Thanks,
Ashok

Comment: What is preventing you from doing so? If you have tried to do this, post your attempt. If not, go do that and then show us what you came up with. At the very least tell us what research you have done.

Comment: LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setText("M-");
b.setWidth("0dip");
b.setHeight("fill_parent");
b.setWeight(1);

Comment: That is not an attempt to add a new button at runtime.

Comment: You can always inflate a `View` from XML at runtime and at it to the current `View` your `Acitvity` or `Fragment` is showing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering you are a newbie:

```
Button myButton = new Button(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
lparms.weight = 1;
lparms.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
myButton.setLayoutParams(lparms);
myButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android_btn_md));
myButton.setOnClickListener(btnMMClick);
myButton.setText("M-");
myButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
myButton.setTextSize(25);
myButton.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: I have always created buttons in XML so this is first time I needed to do this.  You have provided exactly what I am looking for.  Thank you very much Ashok